# Flutter webrtc for simulcast

Tags: flutter, dart, webrtc

I am trying to create an application like Unacademey.It is a learning-platform for the preparation of really tough exams which are conducted in India. like IIT or NEET.So I need to create a UI where the teacher will broadcast himself and Students can see the lecture. also if the student has any confusion then he can ask on the same screen.

So basically, as far as I researched I want to share my screen, so that teacher can show the questions. and also he is able to draw the solution and explanation. And also share his video and audio. and also on the same screen, a Q&A will be there for any type of communication. 
I have created an end to end peer connection.
One user can transmit audio and video to another user.
But this is not my requirement. I want to broadcast my live screen and also record them.
and I didn't find any solution over the internet. and also, the Full document is also not provided in the pub.dev.

Please help me if you can.
I also looked at the concept of WebSockets.
But I am still stuck.

If I ask my question in one line then."HOW CAN I GO ONLINE WITH WEBRTC"
Please reply. I am eagerly waiting for your reply.
Thank you.